# N/A problem in Excel while using VLOOKUP for decimal numbers

Tags: excel, decimal, vlookup

I am trying to use VLOOKUP to retrieve numbers form range of values. While numbers are Integer there is no problem and code works correct. But when numbers turns to decimals, I receive N/A error from the same code. Anyone has a clue? VLOOKUP function does not work for decimals?
Here is the code and numbers

```
VLOOKUP(K21,W33:Y39,3,1)


K21=1

W33:Y39 is:
Lower Upper range
1   2   6
2   3   10
3   4   16
5   11  19
11  20  23
20  49  27
50      35
```

When K2=1.1 VLOOKUP function does not work and the output turns to N/A.
Cell format is general. When I changed it to Numbers the problem does not solved.
Here I attached the file sample [VLOOKUP sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwf0nebesbcp5of/VLOOKUP.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Does your lookup value have the same decimals as column 3 rounded to 3 dp not just formatted?

Comment: Is the decimal value in cell K21 less than 1 (e.g. `0.5`)? That's the only way I can replicate the error, and the problem has nothing to do with decimal, it's that the number is smaller than your smallest lookup value (`1` in this case) so it can't find a match, hence the `#N/A` error.

Comment: You could account for that by validating the input value: `=IF(K21="","",IF(ISNUMBER(K21),IF(K21<MIN($W$33:$W$39),"value too small",VLOOKUP(K21,$W$33:$Y$39,3)),"input must be numeric"))`

Comment: Are the numbers in the lower column actual numbers and not text strings?

Comment: @SolarMike No. decimals value are just for column 1.

Comment: @tigeravatar No. Cell K21 starts from 1 and column 1 starts from 1.1

Comment: @ScottCraner no. they are not actual numbers. They are General.

Comment: Well you say “no” to all of us. Show an example of the decimals AND what you have in K21.

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry. I attached the file sample

Comment: show it as you did the first cells...

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks. I found the problem. lower limit must start from 0.